# Ionic 2 - How do I pass id parameter into "http get" function so that it only display data of specific user and not all

Tags: angular, ionic2

I am trying to load data from db server. I have a quick question: How do I pass specific user id into http get request so that it only fetch data for that user and not the entire data. I am using mongodb as db and Ionic 2 as a front-end.

Below is my code:

Home.html

```html
<ion-card *ngFor="let item of items" (click)="goToOtherPage(item._id)" class="container">
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-avatar item-left>
        <!--<img [src]="item.image" />-->
      </ion-avatar>
      <h2 [innerHTML]="item.patient.name"></h2>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</ion-card>
```

Home.ts

```js
load() {

  let params = {
    userId: '123'
  };

  this.tunzaProvider.load()
    .then(data => {
      this.items = data;
    });

}
```

Provider.ts

```js
load() {


  return new Promise(resolve => {

    this.http.get(this.apiUrl + 'getusertunzas')
      .map(res => res.json())
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.data = data;
        resolve(this.data);
      });
  });

}
```

Comment: Which http method you want to use? get or post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Home.ts**

```
load(id: number) {
        let params = {
            userId: id
        };
        this.tunzaProvider.load(param)
            .subscribe(data => {
                this.items = data;
            }, err => {
                console.error(err);
            });
    }
```

**provider.ts**

http get method:

```
    load(param) {
        let headers = new Headers({
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        });
        return this.http.get(`${baseURL}/getusertunzas/${param.userId}`, {
                headers: headers
            })
            .map((response: Response) => {
                return response.json();
            })
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }
```

http post method:

```
    load(param) {
        let headers = new Headers({
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        });
        return this.http.post(`${baseURL}/getusertunzas`, JSON.stringify(param), {
                headers: headers
            })
            .map((response: Response) => {
                return response.json();
            })
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }
```

error handler (catch error of each call in handleError method):

```
handleError(error) {
    console.error(error);
    return Observable.throw(error || 'Server error');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I will try and let know if that works for me

Comment: @JBhatt, did you try?

Comment: Finally I had time to try this and it works great :). Thanks for the answer. Also, I used post method in some places instead of get.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of one of my service methods that get by Id:

```
getProduct(id: number): Observable<IProduct> {
    if (id === 0) {
        return Observable.of(this.initializeProduct());
    };
    const url = `${this.baseUrl}/${id}`;
    return this.http.get(url)
        .map(this.extractData)
        .do(data => console.log('getProduct: ' + JSON.stringify(data)))
        .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

Hopefully you can apply it to your example.

The key part of this code is the url. Notice the Id is passed as a parameter on the URL.